# What does the word "tchop" mean?

Tags: sens, traduction, argot, france

I have been hearing the word "tchop" a lot in the lyrics of French music. [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=tchop&op=translate) could not translate it, so it appears to be a slang. I have tried looking it up but could not find a meaning. Does it have just one meaning or have multiple meanings depending on context? Artist Aya Nakamura has an entire song named [Tchop](https://google.com/search?q=tchop+aya+nakamura) and KeBlack has a [song](https://google.com/search?q=tchop+keblack) too with the same name. In one of her other songs Sentiments grandissants, Aya Nakamura's lyrics say:

> *On est dans cette vibe, qués-blo dans la tchop, on est dans cette vibe*

and in another song Mon chéri, she says:

> *Toi et moi, babe, posés dans la tchop, babe.*

Comment: Be careful that using that kind of vocabulary you take the risk of not being understood by many people. I'm probably not a reference but I have a harder time understanding her lyrics than lyrics in English...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Le mot tchop appartient à l’argot des jeunes adultes mais il désigne
> deux choses très différentes selon l’endroit où on se trouve. En
> France, dans la plupart des cas, une tchop (plus rarement sous la
> forme une tchops), c’est tout simplement une voiture.
>
> Ce mot s’emploie en particulier quand il est question de certaines
> activités qui sont pratiquées en voiture : faire un tour pour se
> balader, écouter de la musique, traîner avec des amis. Le mot tchop
> évoque donc le plaisir de rouler, le confort de sa propre voiture.
>
> Tchop a plusieurs synonymes argotiques : une ride, une gova. On trouve
> aussi un gamos, qui fait plutôt référence à une voiture avec un moteur
> puissant, une grosse cylindrée.
>
> D’où vient le mot tchop ? Difficile à dire… Il est employé en français
> au moins depuis 2011 et il est probablement apparu dans le sud de
> Paris. Une chanson d’Aya Nakamura sortie en novembre 2020 lui donne
> une certaine visibilité. Extrait des paroles : « J’arrive dans ma
> tchops, tchop, tchop / Toi t’es dans le flops, flop, flop ».
>
> L’autre mot tchop Il existe un autre mot tchop plus ancien, qui
> désigne cette fois la nourriture, un plat, l’action de manger et par
> extension une marchandise. Ce mot est surtout employé au Cameroun,
> dans l’argot camfranglais pratiqué dans les grandes villes.
>
> Le camfranglais est un argot qui se construit en empruntant des mots à
> des sources diverses. Tchop dans le sens de « nourriture » provient du
> pidgin-english tchop, qui le tient de l’anglais chew up, « mâcher,
> mâchouiller ».

Voici une traduction (using [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator)) en anglais (avec un couple de modifications) :

> The word tchop belongs to the slang of young adults but it means two
> very different things depending on where you are. In France, in most
> cases, a tchop (more rarely in the form of a tchops) is simply a car.
>
> This word is used particularly when it comes to certain activities
> that are practiced in a car: taking a ride, listening to music,
> hanging out with friends. The word tchop thus evokes the pleasure of
> driving, the comfort of one's own car.
>
> Tchop has several slang synonyms: a ride, a gova. There is also a
> gamos, which refers to a car with a powerful engine, a big
> displacement.
>
> Where does the word chop come from? Difficult to say... It is used in
> French at least since 2011 and it probably appeared in the south of
> Paris. A song by Aya Nakamura released in November 2020 gives it some
> visibility. Excerpt from the lyrics: "J'arrive dans ma tchops, tchop,
> tchop / Toi t'es dans le flops, flop, flop".
>
> The other word tchop...There is another, older word tchop, which this
> time designates food, a dish, the action of eating and by extension a
> commodity. This word is mainly used in Cameroon, in the Camfranglais
> slang practiced in the big cities.
>
> Camfranglais is a slang that is constructed by borrowing words from
> various sources. Tchop in the sense of "food" comes from the
> pidgin-english tchop, which takes it from the English chew up, "mâcher, mâchouiller".

Source : https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-tchop

Voir aussi : https://www.cnews.fr/culture/2020-11-13/que-signifie-tchop-le-titre-du-nouveau-morceau-daya-nakamura-1017586

Answer (score 3):

In France "tchop" means "voiture" and in camfranglais  slang (Cameroon, big towns) it means "la nourriture", or "un plat", or the act of eating (l’action de manger) ([ref.](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/definition-tchop)).